# get page title, url and excerpt of a page

Tags: page-template, pages

I have the following setup: the front-page is setup as 'static' and it uses a theme page template. On this template / front-page, I need to get the page title, URL and excerpt of the About page.

I found this code that does exactly what I need, but I'm wandering if there's a different approach to this, one that would not use the page ID but the page slug or title.

```
<?php
    $page_id = 13;
    $page_data = get_page( $page_id );
    $the_excerpt = $page_data->post_excerpt;
    $title = $page_data->post_title;
?>
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink(13); ?>">
    <?php echo $page_data->post_title; ?>
</a>
```

**Later edit:** Based on the answer provided by peteroak, this is the complete working code:

```
<?php
    $page = get_page_by_title( 'About' );
    $the_excerpt = $page->post_excerpt;
    $page_data = get_page( $page );
    $title = $page_data->post_title;
?>
<header class="entry-header">
    <h1 class="entry-title">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( get_page_by_title( 'About' ) ) ); ?>">
            <?php echo $page_data->post_title; ?>
        </a>
    </h1>
</header>   
    <div class="entry-content"><?php echo $page->post_excerpt; ?>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( get_page_by_title( 'About' ) ) ); ?>">more +</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: hi found this trend code supply above is what i am looking for but I have no idea why the '<?php echo $page->post_excerpt; ?>' is not working!! can you tell me what i miss! thank's in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the codex has exacly what you need: [`get_page_by_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title)

### Example

```
 $page = get_page_by_title( 'About' );
 $the_excerpt = $page->post_excerpt;
```

or

```
 $page = get_page_by_path( 'parent-page/sub-page' );
```

Comment: i didn't knew that function exists. I made similar function a while ago. I guess i don't need that anymore :)

Comment: Thanks for helping! I will update my post with the complete code that solves the problem.

Comment: glad i could help :)

Answer (score 2):

### Use the public API *everywhere*

Inside the loop, you can use [`get_the_excerpt()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_the_excerpt/) (without arguments). It's better than `$post/$page->excerpt`, as it also attaches the filters and checks if the page/post has a password.

Comment: I didn't used a loop for this, would it made any real difference - performance wise - if I use a loop with this code or not?

Comment: In this case, you'd have to recreate the whole functions internals - see the link in the answer ↑ above.